# Where can Intents be called

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Launching intent from a class outside an activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354768/launching-intent-from-a-class-outside-an-activity)

I was just wondering can a intent be used from a POJO class or must it be used in one that extends Activity?  If it can how would you implement if?

```
public class DataManager{

public DataManager (){}


public void get ()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent (null,Webservice.class);
    intent.putExtra("uri", "http://someuri/service/users/id/21001");
    startActivity (intent);
}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, `startActivity()` is method of Activity class. Not any java class method. So to access this method in other **pojo class** you have to use `Context` of activity.

You can do something like,

```
public class DataManager{

 Context mContext;

 public DataManager (Context context){
 mContext = context;
 }    

 public void get ()
 {
    Intent intent = new Intent (mContext,Webservice.class);
    intent.putExtra("uri", "http://someuri/service/users/id/21001");
    mContext.startActivity (intent);
 }
}
```

**Update:**

One thing to be noted is your Intent code line,

```
Intent intent = new Intent (null,Webservice.class);
```

what is **null** ? You have to put reference of Activity class as a first parameter of Intent constructor. Just check it.

So the code line will be,

```
Intent intent = new Intent (mContext,Webservice.class);
```

Comment: `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` :)

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem - Its only needed when you want to put your activity in new Task. Its not necessary.

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Comment: @user370305 : I would pass `Context` to the `get(...)` method of `DataManager` to prevent the possibility of memory leaks.

Comment: @user370305 a `Broadcast Receiver` also have the `Context` in `onRecive`. you can start `Activity` using that context...

Answer (score 2):

yes you can call an `Activity` from any other class. After passing a reference of the `Context` of your `Current Activity` to that class. for example...

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(mContext, newActivity.class);
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
mContext.startActivity(myIntent);
```